# How can I set the branch method used by glpk solver through pyomo?

Tags: python, pyomo, glpk

**glpsol.exe --help provides the following options:**

Options specific to the MIP solver:

--nomip consider all integer variables as continuous (allows solving MIP as pure LP)

--first branch on first integer variable

--last branch on last integer variable

--mostf branch on most fractional variable

--drtom branch using heuristic by Driebeck and Tomlin
(default)

Answer (score 0):

## To use --first as branch method

import pyomo.environ as pe

opt_solver = pe.SolverFactory("glpk")

opt_solver.options["first"] = ""